# Convert IEnumerable <T> to LookUp<T,K>

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a function that returns `IEnumerable` of the following class

```
public class User
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public IList<string> MemberOf { get; set; }
}
```

How can i convert IEnumerable to LookUp
 the key will be the user name and the value is list of memberOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<User> seq = ...;    
ILookup<string, IList<string>> lookup = seq.ToLookup(u => u.UserName, u => u.MemberOf);
```